# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error occurring in component preview in opened state

Tags: 2013, component

I am facing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error with component preview in component opened state. It is rendering the preview correctly with same component and component template in component closed state as well as in Template Builder.

I tried to remove all the TBBs from the component template, render the component with default component template but in all the cases it is throwing the same error in component opened state.

I checked this for other schema which have the same definition and it is working as expected in all the above mentioned cases.

So, please suggest any solution to identify and resolve this issue.

Comment: Please add logs (Event Viewer)

Comment: Please update your question with detailed error (if possible) to get a good answer. Also make sure you are previewing in correct publication as most of time while opening a shared component we open it from parent publication and it's quite possible some items missing there.

Comment: Does your component have any external items like image from some other system? If yes, then check if that external system is working properly. Because I have seen that when image system is down you typically get this error.

Comment: check your previewPath  in cm config  "%TRIDION_HOME%\config"  & clean the directory and try. path will look like "drive:\Program Files\Tridion\web\Preview\"